# return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Tags: c#

So I am passing in a password string from my home.aspx to the authentication class with this method:

authentication.cs:

```
public hashPassword(string password)
{
    string hashedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "MD5");
    return hashPassword;
}
```

However it gives me an error saying "return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `public string hashPassword(string password)`?

Comment: you dont have return type for the method

Comment: What is the name of the class containing this `hashPassword` method?

Comment: I thought I made it clear, "authentication" Ill update now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to change the variable name as it conflicts with the method name, and then add a return type to your method.

```
public string hashPassword(string password)
{
    string hashed = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "MD5");
    return hashed;
}
```

Comment: True unless the class is named `hashPassword`

Comment: Can I ask, why is it important to put string hashPassword (string password) ? Why is just hashPassword (string password) not acceptable?

Comment: Yes, It's not acceptable in C#, functions should have a return type

Comment: Yes that is correct. Can you explain why it isnt allowed? and why is public void acceptable though?